# Powershell script help needed - Find word beginning with something and replace it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change a string within a file to a string with timestamp on the end but cant work out how to find the initial string using a regex in Powershell

```
(Get-Content sw.js).replace('SW-cache-v.*', 'SW-cache-v'+$(Get-Date -format "s")) | Set-Content sw.js
```

the `SW-cache-v.*` isn't working for me, I'm just not picking up the string in order to replace it.

Any thoughts on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, the `-replace` [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) uses regex matching with string replacement.

```
$Replace = "SW-cache-v{0}" -f (Get-Date -format s)
(Get-Content sw.js) -replace 'SW-cache-v.*',$Replace | Set-Content sw.js
```

---

Keep in mind that `.*` greedily matches all characters until the end of the current line here. For example, if you wanted to only match up until but excluding the next `"` character, you could use a negated character class `[^]`:

```
(Get-Content sw.js) -replace 'SW-cache-v[^"]*',$Replace | Set-Content sw.js
```

The [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) .NET method does a literal string replacement (case-sensitively).

```
# Wildcards and regex are not allowed with .Replace()
'SW-cache-v extra chars'.Replace('SW-cache-v.*','newstring')
SW-cache-v extra chars

# Literal matching is used by .Replace()
'SW-cache-v.*'.Replace('SW-cache-v.*','newstring')
newstring
```

`-replace` defaults to case-insensitive matching. The `-creplace` operator respects the case.

Comment: You make a really good point here about the greedy match - I need to keep the " on the end of the string  -  how would you limit the characters you were replacing so it would stop when it gets to the closing " ?

Comment: You can use `[^"]*`. I added an example of that.

Comment: Thank you so much - been at this nearly all day!